# How to move drop down arrow to top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using icons from icomoon.I want to put a dropdown menu with the user.It works but the problem is the arrow button is coming down.Is it possible to keep the arrow button at the top(I mean near to the head of the icon).Please see the screenshot

[image]

This is my navbar code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#" class="icon-store"></a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle icon-user2" data-toggle="dropdown" > <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this is the style.css for the image icon

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?-8mvsu3');
    src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-8mvsu3') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.woff?-8mvsu3') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?-8mvsu3') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/icomoon.svg?-8mvsu3#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-search:before {
    content: "\e600";
}
.icon-users:before {
    content: "\e601";
}
.icon-lock:before {
    content: "\e602";
}
.icon-cogs:before {
    content: "\e603";
}
.icon-bubbles:before {
    content: "\e604";
}
.icon-pawn:before {
    content: "\e605";
}
.icon-box-add:before {
    content: "\e606";
}
.icon-signup:before {
    content: "\e607";
}
.icon-equalizer:before {
    content: "\e608";
}
.icon-bars:before {
    content: "\e609";
}
.icon-disk:before {
    content: "\e60a";
}
.icon-user:before {
    content: "\e60b";
}
.icon-user2:before {
    content: "\e60c";
}
.icon-stackoverflow:before {
    content: "\e60e";
}
.icon-store:before {
    content: "\e60f";
}
.icon-trash:before {
    content: "\e60d";
}
```

Comment: `.caret { vertical-align: top; }` that's what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

you can  use **vertical-align** property is supported in all major browsers.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

Comment: I think it may have to do with line-height...or a bad icon set

Comment: Can you please tell me how to increase the size of the icon?If I use vertical-align:top It appears like arrow goes to top and the icon comes to down.I think if i crease the icon then it will look good

Comment: you can use "font-size" to change the size of icon and it's up to you to change size or use vertical-align to sets the vertical alignment of an element

Answer (score 1):

To get the arrow aligned to the top, use `.caret { vertical-align: top; }` or play with another values to see if you can get the desire effect. Here you have a list of possible values: [W3C Wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)

Try with this ones:

- vertical-align: text-top
- vertical-align: text-bottom
- vertical-align: middle
- vertical-align: top

If you want to change the `.caret` size, you have to change the three border-size declared. Because it is not an icon, is a triangle made with CSS ([CSS3 Shapes](http://www.css3shapes.com/)):

```
border-left: 4px solid transparent;
border-right: 4px solid transparent;
border-top: 4px solid;
```

Change the `4px` to whatever you want.